# I would like a button in a sticky header to turn red on downscroll

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, elementor

Hi there and thanks in advance for all help

I’m working on a wordpress website and I am using Elementor and Elementor Pro.
I have a button in a sticky header. When people start scrolling down I would like this button to turn red and the text turn white. In a gradual way. (When the colors were the other way around.)

Now I sort of know how to do it but I’m not all sure on everything. I got a guide from a post on Medium which is about turning the whole page a different color which I thought I could tweek a biut to target the button. I'm not totally unfamiliar with a bit of coding but I run into some incompatibilities.
I've added the code from the Medium post below.

What I know:

I need to make a class in CSS ie. .changeColor

And call up this change in a Javascript.

I can add the CSS in the custom CSS part of the widget in Elementor. But where do I put the script.js in the rest of the files? WordPress only has .php files I can get into and because I’m working in Elementor, should or can I place it somewhere else?

Also do i put the transition time in the CSS that describes the button or in the CSS that describes the change?

Many thanks for whoever could make all this a bit clearer for me. THANKS!

Colin

Beginsituation:

```
body {
    background: white;
    transition: 0.3s all;
}
```

What needs to happen on scroll

```
.changeColor {
    background: red;
}
```

A little Javascript

```
$(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $(‘body’).addClass(‘changeColor’)
      }
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
         $(‘body’).removeClass(‘changeColor’)
      }
   });
});
```

`

And add a bit of code to the HTML document that refers to the google hosted library for javascript

Comment: Hi, @Colin can you tell me which wordpress editor you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

first of all you should add give an id to your button so jquery can get it throught that

now create a class which you will add in your button when page srolls

```
.btnChanged{
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
}
```

ok so now create a RAW JS file element you can add it from add new element section and put your js

```
    $(function() {
   $(window).scroll(function () {
      if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
         $('#yourId_which_you_gave_to_btn').addClass('btnChanged')
      }
      if ($(this).scrollTop() < 50) {
         $('#yourId_which_you_gave_to_btn').removeClass('btnChanged')
      }
   });
});
```

hope this will help

Comment: you have to add an element name RAW js in which you can put your scripts

Comment: or you can also put that script in your footer.php or header.php they both already have a script tag put this inside your script tags just don't put it inside any funcitons

Comment: Thanks @HUSSAIN! But where do I put the JS script?

Comment: Ah! Ok I will try that. Thanks so much!

Comment: My pleasure @ColinKassies , hope it will work for you